# CSS.Text centered inside a DIV and controlling vertical align

Tags: css, html

I want to display text in several lines inside a `div`. And I want that the lines are horizontally centered, which I get by using `text-align:center` in the parent `div`.
The problem is that I want these text lines (contained in `span`) to have a small interline distance. 
So, a single `<br>` is enough for me. I have tried to set `margin` and `padding` to the `<span>` elements, but without success.
If I try to position them `absolute`, it doesn't work with the horizontal `alignment` in the parent.
So, how can I have them horizontally centered and control by pixels the spaces interlines?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the `line-height`?

Comment: Show some code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Span elements are inline by default, which means that margins and padding don't apply. Either use divs instead or do this, and then apply margins and/or padding.

```
div.myParentDivClass span {display: inline-block;}
```

Line-height may also get the job done, but it doesn't offer as much control, especially between individual span elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the **vertical-align** property but in order to use it you need to set the display property to **display:table-cell;**

**http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/gntAq**

```
<div>
    <span class="text">My Text To Align Vertically</span>
</div>
```

basically you can mimic the table behavior with CSS like this

```
div {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;        
}

.text {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align